# How can I abort saving an entity within a method annotated with onBeforeSave of a class that extends AbstractRepositoryEventListener?

Tags: java, spring, repository-pattern

I am extending AbstractRepositoryEventListener in order to create a md5 hash of an photo and save it with the object.

I'd like to abort saving the photo altogether in the event of an exception.

```
@Component
public class MyHandler extends AbstractRepositoryEventListener<Photo> {

    @Autowired
    PhotoService photoService;

    @Override
    public void onBeforeSave(Photo photo) {
        File originalPhoto = new File(foto.getUriOriginal());
        try {
            String hash = photoService.getHash(originalPhoto);
            photo.setHash(hash);
        } catch ( IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add boolean field for photo and update it on successful save

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I may not have understand the idea. I don't need a flag to check if the photo has a hash, as I can use the presence or absence of the hash field for that purpose. Perhaps I didn't fully understand the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone ever have this same problem, here's a better approach.

The goal here is basically to validate an entity.

Spring already provides a [ValidatingRepositoryEventListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/event/ValidatingRepositoryEventListener.html) that uses [validators](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) to achieve this goal. Not only will the saving be "aborted", but also the error message will be provided to the client.

It is important to notice that automatic discovery of validators seem to have a bug [with a workaround described here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-validators#4-event-discovery-bug).

It is also possible to create [custom validation annotations](http://dolszewski.com/spring/custom-validation-annotation-in-spring/), as described in the link below, resulting in a more reusable code.

In this particular instance, the Validator would look something like this:

```
@Component("beforeSavePhotoValidator")
public class PhotoValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Photo.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        if (customValidationIsInvalid(obj)){
            errors.rejectValue(
                "<invalidFieldName>",
                "<errorMessageCode>"
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Observe that:

- customValidationIsInvalid, invalidFieldName and errorMessageCode should be appropriately implemented
- the errorMessageCode must be set in the ValidationMessages.properties file
- the workaround must be implemented, or the validator manually registered

Answer (score 0):

You may throw an instance of RuntimeException. It will get Spring to rollback.

There are other more comprehensive ways, details of which you can find [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).